# Python site-packages not recognized on execution, but recognized in Python Console

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, python-3.6

I am attempting to run an sh file from my PyCharm terminal on a Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS virtual machine. I have a virtual environment created for Python 3.6 using MiniConda, where in the settings I can verify that my desired packages (including numpy, scipy, torch, etc.) are installed. When writing `pip install numpy`, I can verify that the requirement is already satisfied `/home/username/miniconda3/envs/DenseFusion/lib/python3.6/site-packages`. When writing `python --version` it returns the correct version, 3.6. When moving to the Python Console and running `import numpy` there are no errors (nor for any other package).

After cd'ing to the proper folder (in PyCharm terminal), I run `sudo ./experiments/scripts/eval_linemod.sh` (the location of my desired sh file). This successfully starts, executing the following short amount of code:

`#!/bin/bash

set -x
set -e

export PYTHONUNBUFFERED="True"
export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0

python3 ./tools/eval_linemod.py --dataset_root ./datasets/linemod/Linemod_preprocessed
--model trained_checkpoints/linemod/pose_model_9_0.01310166542980859.pth
--refine_model trained_checkpoints/linemod/pose_refine_model_493_0.006761023565178073.pth`

The python script it executes, eval_linemod.py, returns the following error when starting to import its packages at the start of the script.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named numpy`

This error occurs for any of the packages attempted. I am stumped as to why the script can not recognize the venv site packages, even though all the other steps verify that the venv is reachable. I have never used Linux previous to this and am trying to follow the DenseFusion github page instructions. If I am missing a very simple characteristic of Linux, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to run the script with `sudo`? When using `sudo` you're executing the command as user `root` which probably won't see the `site-packages` of your regular user, and might even be using a different interpreter.

Comment: Just remove the `sudo` and leave the path to the script. `sudo` is prepended to a command when you need to execute some "administrative" task that requires elevated privileges, the most typical being installing packages on the system. It is not typically required for running number crunching scripts.